# parent process creates shared memory buffer. Now, N child processes must read records from shared memory one after another and evaluate them

Tags: c, fork, semaphore, shared-memory

In c programming, I have prepared buffer of records from table(DB). Now i have all records in buffer.

I have created shared memory and attached this buffer to it.

After shared memory creation, I have used fork to create 5 child processes in loop.

I am using semaphore, so that, buffer can be accessed by only one child process at a time.

Now, within child process flow, I want all 5 child  processes, must read next record from buffer and process it. How can i implement and maintain current count/index and total number of records in between child processes.

Comment: It sounds like a xy problem. Why not sharding the records to every process instead of one-by-one in turn?

Comment: I can't see a question. Or any code.

Comment: @liliscent yes, complete buffer with all records has been shared with child processes. My concern here is.. when child process will read records, it should not happen that, all child processes will pick same/single record. And, how can i maintain same count in all child processes , so that they can update the counter and will read unprocessed record every time

Comment: @niranjandeshak I mean **shard**, not shared. Just partition your data so that every process can only touch its own part.

Comment: I did something similar once, using 4 child threads to render 1/4 each of the completed image. I just tell each thread whether they're thread 0,1,2 or 3. In each thread, I just access the memory that I've allotted myself. Using a simple mechanism, each time a thread finishes, I check if I've built-up all 4 parts of the z-buffer yet. Once done, I hit it with a per-pixel phong-shader to get nicely interactive 4D Quaternion Julia Fractals - without resorting to any efforts at optimisation or GPU use.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].